# Hashing password into SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, passwords, hash

I'm hashing a password in SQL directly like this :

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SET @HashThis = 'SecretPizza'

INSERT into Users (UserId,Password)
Values ('CryptTest',HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis))
```

Result :

[image]

When I try and change the `SHA1` Algorithm to `SHA2_256` or `SHA2_512` I get the following error :

[image]

**Question 1** - Is this really supposed to give me chinese like characters ? 
**Question 2** - Those are valid algorithm so how come I can't use them and why is encryption setting `@HashThis` to null?

Comment: What is the data type of column Users.Password?

Comment: don't use `hashbytes` for this - you can't salt using `hashbytes`, and you limit yourself to a poor selection of (already broken) algorithms. Consider instead using `bcrypt` at the application level and inserting the hash generated from that.

Comment: @ChrisDickson It's NVARCHAR. What should it be ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: You get "Chinese like" characters because you are inserting a varbinary value returned by HASHBYTES into an nvarchar column, so SQL Server is trying to interpret the bytes as Unicode code points (characters).

Question 2: Not supported before SQL Server 2012 - see [SQL Server 2008 R2 HASHBYTES SHA2 returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114804/sql-server-2008-r2-hashbytes-sha2-returns-null)

Comment: Ooooo thanks. Now that you explain it I find it so simple ..-_- What should I set my column type to for the best results ?

Comment: VARBINARY, but see answer to Question 2 added. !!

Answer (score 0):

first do

select HASHBYTES('SHA2-256', @HashThis) from dual;

and see what you get..

Comment: Do you still get that if you try `select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis)` - note underscore in the algorithm name not hyphen.

Comment: Yes I do In the question I putted it with and Underscore.