# What is the most secure password hashing algorithm supported by C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As stated above, I would like to know what would be good practice for password hashing, that supported by C#.

Comment: Please read up on password hashing and password encryption. Encryption *is not* Hashing. Also, the context here is very vague as to what the end-goal is and why it matters that SQL Server supports this hashing (or "encryption") at all.

Comment: What do you mean by being hashed and compared in both SQL Server and C#?  Ordinarily the password would be hashed in .NET and then compared against your SQL data.  You can hash in SQL as well, but the options are more limited.

Comment: OK, I see the point, therefore, I would edit question.

Comment: @user2246674 I ment hashing, and I edited question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691253/hashing-password-into-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure why you need the ability to hash in both SQL and C#.

Regardless, SQL will likely be the limiting factor in your algorithm choice.

[SQL Server 2012 supports SHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) (as does .NET), and that would be a very secure option.

But the best you could do with [SQL Server 2008 is SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

---

I see you changed your question.

If it were me I'd hash with .NET and also store a salt as explained [here](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx).  Then you would never hash with SQL.  And if you want the most secure algorithm, then use [SHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx).

Comment: +1 to counteract the 'hateraid'... Oh god, did I just say that?!